# Adding custom domain names to an Azure webapp in a Nested traffic manager profile

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I want to have the following setup in Azure.
* Main Traffic manager
           - WebAppA (West Europe)
           - Nested Endpoint
                  * WebAppB (West Europe)

WebappA has a custom domain name linked with a CName to the main traffic manager.
Now WebAppB also needs this custom domain name, but I'm not possible to add this.
I receive the message "Hostname is already being used in the following App WebAppA".

What I want to achieve is to have 2 WebApps running in the same datacenter with a Traffic manager on top to have better control control over the setup while doing BlueGreen deployments.
We currently have a setup spread over 2 datacenters, but we experience a lot of latency while hopping to the SQL server in WestEurope from UKSouth?

Is there any setup what can make this work?

Comment: Is the reply below working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to raise a support ticket where MS engineers can force add the Custom Domain if you are able to prove your Domain ownership.

The error which you are getting has nothing to do with the Traffic Manager Nested configuration. Since you have added the Custom Domain to the WebApp A, you are not able to add it to the Web App B due to some validation check.

Comment: I'm also hitting this validation check, and I think the validation is wrong.. The portal UI should allow bypassing of this check with a tick box "I know it's in use on another site but I know what I'm doing and want to add it to this site" :)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two methods.

You could associate the same hostname to multiple web apps regardless of subscription (or even AAD tenant!) using the `awverify` method of validating domains. That is to create two TXT records for your two web app services.

```
Hostname — awverify.targethostname.yourdomain.com
Set type = TXT
value = <yourwebappname>.azurewebsites.net
TTL — short. Like seconds or minutes.
```

You could get more details from this blog: [Azure Traffic Manager with Web Apps in different subscriptions](https://jpd.ms/azure-traffic-manager-with-web-apps-in-different-subscriptions-75877d22a34b).

Another option is to assign the same hostname to Web Apps in **different app service plans**.  Bear in mind that if you're using IP addresses/A records in your DNS, you'd need both web apps to have different IP addresses for the DNS to be able to differentiate between your web apps. Read the details in the [the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143780/is-it-possible-to-move-custom-domain-from-one-web-app-to-another).